# Pointer In Function Name / Pointer Function

Tags: c, pointers, visual-c++

I'm learning C, I was looking at https://github.com/mruby/mruby/blob/master/src/load.c and this line made me very confused:

```
mrb_irep* read_irep_record_1
```

On line 40.

I can see that this is a pointer of some sort.
What I'd like to know is the following
What does this do? 
How do you use them? 
What are these called? 
How do they work? 
How can I replicate this in a program?
I've only this used in C projects, is it recommended to use these in C++? Can you do this in C++?

I searched a bit on Stackoverflow for pointer functions but couldn't find anything like this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you referring to line 40 of that code?

Comment: It's just a pointer to a [regular struct called `mrb_irep`](https://github.com/mruby/mruby/blob/232ec102d6264cd5e79cf4e900a5cc946ca76a67/include/mruby/irep.h#L28). Your questions are rather basic, and they require long answers. I suggest reading a book or googling for C or C++ introduction.

Comment: I'm reading C Primer Plus.

Comment: Then read [page 657](http://books.google.no/books?id=MAAuAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA657&lpg=PA657&dq=c+primer+function+pointers&source=bl&ots=Y-l9agVtE0&sig=32BBSDvtIUavFmD4ZkamHKqIApw&hl=no&sa=X&ei=yJ2YU9iaCMr8ywPHnIDYCg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=c%20primer%20function%20pointers&f=false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line is simply declaring a function that returns a pointer to `mrb_irep`. For example, what does a function declared as `int foo()` return? Well it returns an `int`, as we see in the declaration. Similarly, a function declared as `mrb_irep* read_irep_record_1(...)` returns a variable of type `mreb_irep*`, or a pointer to a struct called `mreb_irep`.